# Custom message display page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In an Asp.Net Mvc 4 site, there may be various messages needed be shown to end users (e.g. "Thank you. The document has been submitted.", "The item and its depended items have been deleted.", "Cannot find the row with ID of xxx.", "Cannot delete this row because it's xxx is depended on it.", ... etc).

How to (and what's the best approach) define a generic page accept a message and display it? The page should be able to be used by all the controllers in the site.

**Added:**
How about create a `ShowMessage` controller and view which accept Query string/ViewData/TempData and display it. Other controllers redirect the page if needed. Is this a good solution?

Comment: I would recommend to use a property in your viewmodel. for ex:  ViewMessage or ViewErrorMessage in your base view model or the specific viewmodel class..

public ActionResult Index(){

viewModel.ViewMessage = "Hello";

return View(viewModel);
}

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend this:

[toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

It was created by John Papa, who frequents SO on a fairly regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store message in ViewBag/ViewData or TempData and render it to your particular view. You can create extension method in baseController class and hence it will be accessible from all the controller. Check out below blog post that discusses the same.

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/05/03/keep-your-users-informed-with-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a client side notification plugin such as [`jGrowl`](https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl) or [`noty`](http://needim.github.io/noty/).